# What does the compound operator <: mean in languages with type systems?

Tags: types, covariance, contravariance

What do the compound operators "<:" or ">:" mean?
I am seeing this in discussions of type systems, covariance/contravariance.
I am not very familiar with any programming paradigms that make heavy use of type systems.
a link to discussion: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14831290
For when the link stagnates, here is some relevant text:
Covariance and contravariance are just monotonicity and anti-monotonicity, applied to types ordered by subtyping.

That is: if we have a function on types, say, the function `f` defined by:

```
f(x) = Int -> x
```

Then we say `f` is covariant because it is monotone: it preserves the subtype ordering on its argument. That is:

```
if x <: y, then f(x) <: f(y)
```

Similarly, if we consider `f` defined by:

```
f(x) = x -> Int
```

then this `f` is contravariant because it is anti-monotone: it reverses the subtype ordering on its argument. That is:

```
if x <: y, then f(y) <: f(x)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to these discussions, or a quick explanation to give some context?

Comment: @Ash: added link and context from link

Comment: Okay, I found it in Scala. It just means "is a subtype of". I guess I should have been able to infer that from the context in hindsight.